# Create new system-call in xv6 that returns data about an open files for all running processes

Tags: system-calls, xv6

Im started to learn about xv6.
And I'm trying to add a new system call that will print the list of open files for all running processes.
It has to print pid of each process, its file descriptor number (0,1,2- for each pid), if the file is regular or piped and if the file is readable of writable.

So I know is how to get the pid. Here is an example of a code:

```
struct proc *p;
    sti();
    acquire(&ptable.lock);
    cprintf("name \t pid \t type \t \n");
    for (p=ptable.proc; p<&ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++){
        cprintf("%s \t %d  \n", p->name, p->pid);
        }
    }
    release (&ptable.lock);
```

What I don't know and couldn't find on the internet is how to check if file named by file descriptor is writable\riadable\both
And I don't know how to check if the type of the file named by file descriptor is pipe\regular.

I looked at `file.h` and there are fields like `type`(FD_NONE, FD_PIPE, FD_INODE), `char readable,char writable`.
But I dont understand how to get them...

If you have any resources with subtitle info to share with me or if you can help, I would be happy to hear.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Check out

- `struct proc` in `proc.h`
- functions in `file.c`

You should be able to get a pointer to the beginning of the open files array like this:

```
struct file* fp = (struct file*) &p->ofile;
```

From there, you can copy the same syntax from the `ptable` loop to loop through the files. And to check if a file is readable, functions in `file.c` just check the readable flag:

```
if(fp->readable && fp->type == FD_PIPE)
 // do some logic
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.
can you tell me why I should check if type is "pipe" by using

 if (fp->pipe) 

 and not

 if ( fp->type==FD_PIPE)

Comment: Actually you're right. I'll correct it to my answer to `if(f->type == FD_PIPE)`

Comment: @tentative Is```struct file* fp = (struct file*) &p->ofile;```  the only way? It seems to give corrupted data

Comment: @Dani that may happen if the process you're printing for is `UNUSED`. Are you sure that's not the issue?